# How to handle abbreviated year pattern (yy) in Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

Input:

```
{
  "date": "01-JAN-70"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "date": "1970-01-01"
}
```

appreciate your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer that doesn't use string operations, which is not a good practice for dates handling. The function replaceCentury() let's you replace the century of a date with another one.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Dates
fun centuryFromYear(c)=floor( (c / 100)) * 100
// replaceCentury(): d is the input date, c is the century that you want the date to be in
fun replaceCentury(d: Date, c: Number)= date({year: d.year - centuryFromYear(d.year) + c, month: d.month, day: d.day})
var inputDate=payload.date as Date {format: "dd-MMM-yy"} 
---
replaceCentury(inputDate, 1900)
```

Output:

```json
"1970-01-01"
```

Comment: this is working perfectly. Appreciate your input

Answer (score 0):

Try with this approach:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var year = "19" ++ (payload.date splitBy "-")[2]
var fDate = ((payload.date splitBy "-")[0] ++ "-" ++ (payload.date splitBy "-")[1] ++ "-" ++ year) 
---
fDate as Date {"format": "dd-MMM-yyyy"} as String {"format": "uuuu-MM-dd"}
```

Comment: i appreciate your input . I be tried it and it’s working too